# ¿Por qué me da este java.lang.Runtime... cuando intento pasar de un Fragemnt a una activity?

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

Tengo el siguiente `Fragment` que al apretar el botón me dirijo a `MainActivity_program` :

**PageFragment3:**

```
 public class PageFragment3 extends Fragment {

    Button btn;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_3, container,false);

        btn = rootView.findViewById(R.id.boton_empezar);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                start();
            }
        });

        return rootView;

    }

    public void start(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity_program.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

y **MainActivity_program:**

```
public class MainActivity_program extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridLayout mainGrid;
    private Animation animacion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);


        mainGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);
        animacion = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.animacion_pulsar);

        //Set Event
        setSingleEvent(mainGrid);
        //setToggleEvent(mainGrid);
    }

    private void setToggleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        //Loop all child item of Main Grid
        for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
            //You can see , all child item is CardView , so we just cast object to CardView
            final CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (cardView.getCardBackgroundColor().getDefaultColor() == -1) {
                        //Change background color
                        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6F00"));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity_program.this, "State : True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        //Change background color
                        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity_program.this, "State : False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        //Loop all child item of Main Grid
        for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
            //You can see , all child item is CardView , so we just cast object to CardView
            final CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
            final int finalI = i;
            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    cardView.startAnimation(animacion); // PARA LA ANIMACION CUANDO PULSES CUALQUIER CARDVIEW
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity_program.this,ActivityOne.class);
                    intent.putExtra("info","This is activity from card item index  "+finalI);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Dándome el siguiente error:

> 2019-07-24 18:22:33.955 11278-11285/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
>   2019-07-24 18:22:40.014 11278-11278/com.example.imagenes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.imagenes, PID: 11278
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.imagenes/com.example.imagenes.MainActivity_program}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.GridLayout.getChildCount()' on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.GridLayout.getChildCount()' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.imagenes.MainActivity_program.setSingleEvent(MainActivity_program.java:72)
>           at com.example.imagenes.MainActivity_program.onCreate(MainActivity_program.java:43)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Answer (score 0):

El problema se indica aquí:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.imagenes/com.example.imagenes.MainActivity_program}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int

El `Intent` para cargar la `Activity` funciona correctamente pero al cargar `MainActivity` el valor de `mainGrid` es null al llamar el método `setSingleEvent()`, por esta razón no se carga la `Activity`.

```
private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
    //Loop all child item of Main Grid
    for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
        ...
        ...
```

**El problema se debe seguramente a que el `GridLayout` con id `mainGrid` no existe en el archivo `splash_screen.xml` que carga tu clase `MainActivity_program` .**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);


    mainGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);
    ...
    ...
}
```